# using file info from txt file to bull trim audio with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have found how to trim individual audio files with ffmpeg. Is there any way to do it on bulk? I have thousands of audio files each with different segments that need to be saved separately.  The input file, time to start clipping, and duration are all in separate columns, row by row, in a text/excel file.

Comment: ffmpeg can't do this directly. But a batch/shell script can do it.

Comment: Thanks, know of anywhere I can look to get an idea where to start? I'm just learning these things as I go.

Comment: Mentioning your OS or preferred scripting language would narrow down suggestions.

Comment: Using Window 10. I've worked a bit in python and R but am open to something different